# The meaning of "They have emerged with accounts of something"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I can't figure out what "They have emerged with accounts of something" means! No dictionary contained this phrase.

Thanks.

Comment: Context?  "Account" can mean different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, it means **"They came forward with reports of something."**

It sounds like they mean "account" as in:

> an oral or written description of particular events or situations; narrative: an account of the meetings; an account of the trip.
>
> Source:
> http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/account

And "emerged" could just mean:

> to come forth into view or notice, as from concealment or obscurity: a ghost emerging from the grave; a ship emerging from the fog.
>
> Source: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/emerge